# Finding the Ghul Matron in Shadow of Mordor

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I'm currently accomplishing the hunting challenges, and the 9th challenge is to kill a Ghul Matron in the game.

I went through quite a few discussions onto Steam/IGN etc. boards, and mostly they discussed how the Matron's weakness is fire and explosions, and how to get rid of them easily. They do mention something [along the lines of](https://steamcommunity.com/app/241930/discussions/0/613937943179205401/#c613937943179457266):

> you'll need to hang out around ghul mounds at night to get one to come
>   out iirc.

I've been stuck trying to go through caves and all kinds of seedy areas at night times and have only found orcs gatherings or Graugs. I did not encounter any ghouls at all.

Is there a particular Ghul-rich cave? A particular place in the maps (either of them)? Are ghul mounds something different? I just thought that they especially gather around caves and that is what the quote above is referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, **Ghul Mounds** are not a creature, but instead a terrain anomaly caused (lorewise) by Ghuls. Think of mole holes, but instead of having a mole come out, you have 200 Ghuls jumping at you. Here's one:

[image: Here's an example of a mound]

There are only two ways to find them, like you said, one of the methods is in caves. The second one is finding those mounds around non-stronghold areas. One important thing to keep in mind is that they **only spawn at night**. The mounds (and by extension the Ghuls) don't have a fixed spawn, so you may have to run around for a bit (and by using the wait command in the Map to respawn).

Once you found a bunch of **Ghuls** you have to fight them, but **don't kill the fleeying Ghuls** (*The ones with the 3 claws indicator over their heads*). They will run, which triggers the spawn of Ghul Spitters. Repeat the process, and around the 3rd/4th wave a **Ghul Matron** spawns

Comment: Also, worth noting that if you're able to mount Caragors, they're a good way to find the mounds (since you can check all caves/plains quickly)

Comment: If I remember correctly, Ghul Mounds are also introduced as part of the Lord of the Hunt DLC.  But in the base game, Ghuls themselves are no harder to find in the plains at night than Ghul Mounds are in LotH.

Comment: Finally found it. Had to go around several places before encountering first ghul.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the selected answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/319009/21757), a small step-by-step for easier spawning:

1. Tracking some uruks near/around the mound region
2. The game time should be night
3. Start a combat with the uruks, do not use stealth/arrows.
4. Once you reach ~10x combo, the first few ghuls will appear
5. As soon as you notice the first ghul on map, convert the uruks (if any remain) to fight alongside you.
6. Let the ghuls notice you. Do not fight them, just keep double-tapping spacebar around them and let the uruks kill them for you
7. The last 3 ghuls will start running away. Let them leave. They'll dig tunnels in the earth
8. In 20 seconds or so, next batch of ghuls will appear. Follow same steps as 5-6-7. The next wave of ghuls will appear quickly this time (within 5 seconds)
9. The 3rd/4th wave will consist of atleast one Ghul Matron. (in my case, I had 4 matrons appear at the same time)